# Django: Filtering a related field by date yields unwanted results

Tags: django, orm, relational-database

models:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    licence_plate = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class WorkTime(models.Model):
    work_start = models.DateTimeField()
    work_end = models.DateTimeField()
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="work_times")
```

However when I try to filter those working times using:

```
qs = Vehicle.objects.filter(
work_times__work_start__date__gte="YYYY-MM-DD",
work_times__work_end__date__lte="YYYY-MM-DD").distinct()
```

I get results that do not fit the timeframe given. Most commonly when the work_end fits to something, it returns everything from WorkTime

What I would like to have:

```
for vehicle in qs:
    for work_time in vehicle.work_times:
        print(vehicle, work_time.work_start, work_time.work_end)
```

Comment: The filter has no effect on the `.work_times` from the `Vehicle`s, it only will ensure that the `Vehicle`s in the `qs` will contain *at least* one `WorkTime` in the given range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter has no effect on the `.work_times` from the `Vehicle`s, it only will ensure that the `Vehicle`s in the `qs` will contain *at least* one `WorkTime` in the given range.

You can work with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) to allow filtering efficiently on a related manager:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

qs = Vehicle.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'work_times',
        WorkTime.objects.filter(
            work_start__date__range=('2021-03-01', '2021-03-12')
        ),
        to_attr='filtered_work_times'
    )
)
```

and then you can work with:

```
for vehicle in qs:
    for work_time in vehicle.filtered_work_times:
        print(vehicle, work_time.work_start, work_time.work_end)
```

Comment: This solved my problem completely, and also gave me a very nice example of Prefetch(). Thank you very much! Stay awesome, stay safe